# How load Entity data into object - GoogleAppEngine - Low Level API

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, low-level-api

How can  I automatically read a Entity (com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity) into a object using GoogleAppEngine Low Level API?

There is no magic way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Low Level API doesn't provide entity mapping - it just exposes a dict-like interface. If you want mapping, you need to use JDO, JPA, or a third-party library like [Objectify](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/). Personally I'd suggest Objectify as the obviously superior choice.

Comment: if you want to keep it close to low-level API then Objectify is a better choice.